# How to show unsupported character on textview android

Tags: android, textview

I am getting some unsupported character in android, when i try to show that character on textview with default android font then it will be shown without any issue, but same thing i do with custom font the special characters was ommitted, is that any way to show same character

Comment: there is no way to do it. The custom font ttf file maynot have all the characters

Comment: @IllegalArgument so is that any way to find character will be  supported or not by font